# Intellij Can't find file in path

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

we have a java project created with maven with standart folder tree, that generate maven. we put our xml files and log4j propertie files in **resources** folder which locates in one level with **src** folder. in resources folder we have `ApplicationSetting.xml` and in Eclipse when we write in class "resources/Applications.xml", everythong works nice, but not in Intellij. there we get FileNotFoundException. works only if I'll write "Application/resources/ApplicationSetting.xml". is there any way to write file path as in eclipse. in our team somebody uses eclipse, others intellij.

EDIT:
Folder structure is:

- Application

  - resources
  - src

    - main

      - java
  - test

the project name in BackEnd and in it we have 4 modules: Application, Configuration, DataLogic and BusinessLogic. In "Edit Configuration" of Intellij working directory is BackEnd, classpath module is Application

Comment: _What_ was your folder structure again?  Why should it matter if one person is using Eclipse and the other is using IntelliJ?  Are you sure that you're following the traditional Maven folder structure?

Comment: Quick question - What does your actual error say?

Answer (score 0):

Ideal maven structure should be :

```
src
  -main
      -java
      -resources
  -test
      -java
      -resources
```

One disadvantage of your folder structure is manual path setting for your `resources` 
and 
there is no separation between your `source resources` and `test resources`.

Comment: shoul be, but maven 3.3 generated it as I noted in post :)